# How to go through the list and merge some phrases conditionally?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of phrases, and I need to merge some of them: Those phrases that end with `-` should be merged with the next phrase in the list.

For example:

```
phrases = [
   'Title',
   'page',
   'Specification',
   'High speed drilling ma-',
   'chine is aimed at'
]
```

The output should be:

```
merged_phrases = [
   'Title',
   'page',
   'Specification',
   'High speed drilling machine is aimed at'
]
```

I started writing the code but got stuck quickly:

```
merged_phrases = []
for phrase in phrases:
    if phrase[len(phrase)-1] == "-":
        # how can I merge "phrase" with the next one in "phrases"?
    else:
        merged_phrases.append(phrase)
```

How to merge current `phrase` with the next one, and drop the next one from `phrases`?

Comment: What are you stuck on? What do you want the end result to be? Do you really have to use recursion? If so, you need to define a function, which you haven't done here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: I'm not sure if this should be the recursion or not. I would like to hear some recommendations. The expected result is shown in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a traditional `for` loop like this:

```
phrases = [
   'Title',
   'page',
   'Specification',
   'High speed drilling ma-',
    'chine is aimed at'

]
index_lst = []
merged_phrases = []
for index,phrase in enumerate(phrases):
    if index not in index_lst:
        if phrase[-1] == '-':
            merged_phrases.append(phrase[:-1]+phrases[index+1])
            index_lst.append(index+1)
        else:
            merged_phrases.append(phrase)

print(merged_phrases)
```

Output:

```
['Title', 'page', 'Specification', 'High speed drilling machine is aimed at']
```

**Edit:**

If consecutive words in your list have `-` at the end, then you can use this code:

```
phrases = [
   'Title',
   'page',
   'Specification',
   'High speed drilling ma-',
   'chine is aimed at-',
   ' test-',
   ' 123'
]
index_lst = []
merged_phrases = []
for index,phrase in enumerate(phrases):
    curr_phrase = ''
    if index not in index_lst:
        for i,x in enumerate(phrases[index:]):
            if x[-1] == '-':
                curr_phrase += x[:-1]
                index_lst.append(index+i)
            else:
                if curr_phrase != '':
                    merged_phrases.append(curr_phrase+x)
                    index_lst.append(index + i)
                else:
                    merged_phrases.append(phrase)
                break

print(merged_phrases)
```

Output:

```
['Title', 'page', 'Specification', 'High speed drilling machine is aimed at test 123']
```

Comment: What if two consecutive phrases has - at the end

Comment: @RahulK Check out my latest edit. And pls be kind enough to remove that downvote and make sure that u hit the upvote button. Thank you for ur suggestion!

Comment: You're welcome, All good now. And downvote was not from me.  :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you don't need recursion. A little hack will almost do the job:

```
','.join(phrases).replace('-,','').split(',')
```

This will fail if any phrase contain `-,` in it. If you can, you may use any other character or string instead of `,` which wont be there in any phrases

Comment: What if I have comma in a phrase?

Comment: Yes, If you have "-," in any phrase it'll fail, you may fix it using any other character or random string instead of "," that you sure wont be present in any phrase.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
merged_phrases = []
previous_phrase_merged = False
for i, phrase in enumerate(phrases):
  if previous_phrase_merged:
    previous_phrase_merged = False
    continue
  if phrase[-1] == '-':
    merged_phrase = phrase[:-1] + phrases[i + 1]
    merged_phrases.append(merged_phrase)
    previous_phrase_merged = True
  else:
    merged_phrases.append(phrase)
```

The enumeration allows you to access the index of the phrase so you can easily reference the one after it in the list, and the `previous_phrase_merged` acts as a flag so you know when to skip an element if it's just been merged with the phrase from before. I don't think you need recursion for this problem, hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []
parts = []
for phrase in phrases:
    parts.append(phrase)
    if not phrase.endswith('-'):
        result.append(' '.join(parts))
        parts = []
if parts:
    result.append(' '.join(parts))
```

Let me know if you need explanation on this.

Comment: You should add explanation **anyway**. The thing is that these answers are not only for OP but for future references/people with the same question.

Comment: Yeah, too tired atm. Will add explanation later.